# Problema de CORS em API Spring-Rest e front-end Ionic3

Tags: spring-boot, ionic3, spring-security, amazon-aws, spring-rest

Desenvolvi uma aplicação Rest com Back-end utilizando spring-rest e front-end em Ionic. Estou enfrentando um problema de configuração de CORS. Nos métodos dos resources utilizei a anotação `@CrossOrigin` para liberar todas origens que utilizam o recurso, criei uma configuração de segurança conforme abaixo onde tenho o Bean corsConfigurationSource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@CrossOrigin (origins = "*")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/h2-console/**",
            "/categorias/**",
            "/segmento/**",
            "/fabricantes/**"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET = {
            "/localidades/estados/**",
            "/localidades/cidades/**",
            "/localidades/bairros/**",
            "/vendedores/"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST = {
            "/auth/forgot/**",
            "/clientes/**",
            "/clientes/company/**",
            "/vendedores/"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_PUT = {
            "/vendedores/"
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_DELETE = {
            "/vendedores/"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }

        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and().csrf().disable();


        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_PUT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_DELETE).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil));
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil, userDetailsService));
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Quando rodo a aplicação localmente funciona de forma perfeita, então coloquei a API-Rest no Amazon-EC2 para testar, quando a aplicação tenta consumir a API ela retorna o "erro" abaixo.

"has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https"

Quando testo os end-points da API com o PostMan funciona perfeitamente também.

Utilizei este manual para configurar, mas não esta dando certo. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

Como configurar o CORS para que o servidor não bloquei requisições de outras origens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiquei o erro. Analisando a falha com mais calma ela cita que as requisições suportadas deveriam respeitar algum protocolo informado (http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https). Então retornei na configuração da URL base que era "ec2-32-17-12-43.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080" e acrescentei o Http antes "http://ec2-32-17-12-43.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080".